# Is there any way to get the Hex color code of a radar chart column on clicking of a radar label instead of clicking on radar column?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular9, amcharts4

I have been trying to get the Hex color code of the radar column on clicking radar labels but I'm failed. I know how to get Hex color code on clicking the radar column but my requirement is to get the Hex color on clicking the label. Please suggest any ideas. Following is the code to get Hex color on clicking the Column: `series.columns.template.events.on( "hit", function (ev) { //this.onLabelClick(ev.target.dataItem.dataContext["category"]); console.log(ev.target.fill["hex"]); //this.impactService.setColorCode(ev.target.fill["hex"]); console.log(ev.target); }, this );`

Comment: hey, can you provide the codepen or jsfiddle for the same?

Comment: sure @TonyMontana please find the code in the given link https://codepen.io/abhishekkadavergu/pen/qBbzLyQ

Answer (score 0):

You may access the pie column's hex color code by clicking on the radar label by using this :

```
categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.events.on(
    "hit",
    function(ev) {
        chart.series.each(function(series) {
          if (series instanceof am4charts.ColumnSeries) {
            series.columns.each(function(column) {
              if (column.dataItem.categoryX == ev.target.dataItem.category) {
                console.log(column.fill["hex"]);
              }
            })
          }
        })
    },
);
```

This is the reference [link](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/highlighting-column-on-axis-label-click/) of amchart's official documentation and this is the working demo: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/go8hkfte/1/)